# ProgressBar stops spinning at some point while loading data inside activity (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, spinner, block, loading

I have the following screen:

[image]

When I click on `Ponentes` `ImageButton`,  `ProgressBar` appears while the data inside `Ponentes` activity is loading. The problem is that it stops spinning at some point. What may cause the issue and how can I fix it?

Here is the `ProgressBar` in the `Ponentes` `axml`:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id = "@+id/loadingSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Here is the `OnCreate` method of `Ponentes` `Activity`:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SpeakersActivity);

    Android.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    toolbar.NavigationOnClick += delegate
    {
        this.OnBackPressed();
    };


    loadingSpinner = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.loadingSpinner);
    loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //get all the speakers from the db
        allSpeakers = DatabaseHelper.GetAllFromTable<Speaker>("speakers.db");

        //get only the international spakers
        internationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("international")).ToList();

        //get only the national speakers
        nationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("national")).ToList();

        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            speakersRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.speakersRecyclerView);
            speakersLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            speakersRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(speakersLayoutManager);
            speakersAdapter = new SpeakersAdapter(internationalSpeakers);
            speakersAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
            speakersRecyclerView.SetAdapter(speakersAdapter);

            loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        });
     });

     internationalSpeakersTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.internationalSpeakersTextView);
     internationalSpeakersTextView.Click += delegate
     {
            //change TextViews's style when selected/not-selected
            internationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_selected);
            nationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_unselected);

            LoadSpeakers(internationalSpeakers);
     };

     nationalSpeakersTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nationalSpeakersTextView);
     nationalSpeakersTextView.Click += delegate
     {
            //change TextViews's style when selected/not-selected
            nationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_selected);
            internationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_unselected);

            LoadSpeakers(nationalSpeakers);
     };
}
```

If you want I can paste you the entire `Ponentes` `Activity`

Comment: You put the loading onto a separate thread by using Task.Run() but in there you marshal back to the UI thread to update your progressbar (Activity.RunOnUiThread()), this will block the UI thread and your spinner stops running.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: You could share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: While the `ProgressBar` is spinning I get records from a database, and I fill a `RecyclerView` with those records. Is it enought for you if I pass you only the activity of the `OnCreate` method I pasted above, or do you need everything : the activity and its `.axml`, the database and the `RecyclerView's` adapter and view holder definitions?

Comment: You could use static data in your sample .

Answer (score 0):

`SpeakersActivity.cs` :

```
[Activity(Label = "SpeakersActivity", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SpeakersActivity : BaseActivity
{
    TextView internationalSpeakersTextView;

    TextView nationalSpeakersTextView;

    RecyclerView speakersRecyclerView;

    // Layout manager that lays out each card in the RecyclerView:
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager speakersLayoutManager;

    // Adapter that accesses the data set (speakers):
    SpeakersAdapter speakersAdapter;

    /// <summary>
    /// List that contains all the speakers
    /// </summary>
    List<Speaker> allSpeakers;

    /// <summary>
    /// List that contains the international speakers
    /// </summary>
    List<Speaker> internationalSpeakers;

    /// <summary>
    /// List that contains the national speakers
    /// </summary>
    List<Speaker> nationalSpeakers;

    ProgressBar loadingSpinner;

    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SpeakersActivity);

        Android.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        toolbar.NavigationOnClick += delegate
        {
            this.OnBackPressed();
        };

        loadingSpinner = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.loadingSpinner);
        loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //get all the speakers from the db
            allSpeakers = GetAllSpeakers();

            //get only the international spakers
            internationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("international")).ToList();

            //get only the national speakers
            nationalSpeakers = allSpeakers.Where(x => x.Nationality.Equals("national")).ToList();

            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                speakersRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.speakersRecyclerView);
                speakersLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                speakersRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(speakersLayoutManager);
                LoadSpeakers(internationalSpeakers);

                loadingSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            });
        });

        internationalSpeakersTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.internationalSpeakersTextView);
        internationalSpeakersTextView.Click += delegate
        {
            //change TextViews's style when selected/not-selected
            internationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_selected);
            nationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_unselected);

            LoadSpeakers(internationalSpeakers);
        };

        nationalSpeakersTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nationalSpeakersTextView);
        nationalSpeakersTextView.Click += delegate
        {
            //change TextViews's style when selected/not-selected
            nationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_selected);
            internationalSpeakersTextView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textView_unselected);

            LoadSpeakers(nationalSpeakers);
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load speakers inside activity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="speakers">speakers</param>
    private void LoadSpeakers(List<Speaker> speakers)
    {
        speakersAdapter = new SpeakersAdapter(speakers);
        speakersAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
        speakersRecyclerView.SetAdapter(speakersAdapter);
    }

    private void OnItemClick(object sender, string speakerResumeUrl)
    {
        var speakerDetailsActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(SpeakerDetailsActivity));
        speakerDetailsActivity.PutExtra("speakerResumeUrl", speakerResumeUrl);
        StartActivity(speakerDetailsActivity);
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(CongressActivity));
        Finish();
    }

private List<Speaker> GetAllSpeakers()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

        List<Speaker> speakers = new List<Speaker>();
        speakers.Add(new Speaker { Photo = "https://i.imgur.com/DDH2Ckk.png", Name = "Anne-Maree Keenan", Resume = "https://51congresopodologia.com/?page_id=4004", Nationality = "international" });
        speakers.Add(new Speaker { Photo = "https://i.imgur.com/DDH2Ckk.png", Name = "Anthony Redmond", Resume = "https://51congresopodologia.com/?page_id=4004", Nationality = "international" });
        speakers.Add(new Speaker { Photo = "https://i.imgur.com/DDH2Ckk.png", Name = "Chris Nester", Resume = "https://51congresopodologia.com/?page_id=4004", Nationality = "national" });
        speakers.Add(new Speaker { Photo = "https://i.imgur.com/DDH2Ckk.png", Name = "Amol Saxena", Resume = "https://51congresopodologia.com/?page_id=4004", Nationality = "international" });

        return speakers;
    }
}
```

`SpeakersActivity.axml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/appColor"
        android:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_back_button">
        <TextView
            android:text="Ponentes"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_weight="10">
        <TextView
            android:text="Internacionales"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/internationalSpeakersTextView"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/textView_selected"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Nacionales"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/nationalSpeakersTextView"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/textView_unselected"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/speakersRecyclerView"
        android:layout_weight="90"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id = "@+id/loadingSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"/>
        <!--android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/animdraw"-->
</LinearLayout>
```

`SpeakersAdapter.cs` :

```
public class SpeakersAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public event EventHandler<string> ItemClick;
    public List<Speaker> listOfSpeakers;

    public SpeakersAdapter(List<Speaker> speakers)
    {
        listOfSpeakers = speakers;
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return listOfSpeakers.Count; }
    }

    void OnClick(int position)
    {
        if (ItemClick != null)
            ItemClick(this, listOfSpeakers[position].Resume);
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        SpeakerViewHolder vh = holder as SpeakerViewHolder;

        var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(listOfSpeakers[position].Photo);
        vh.speakerPhotoImageView.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        vh.speakerNameTextView.Text = listOfSpeakers[position].Name;
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                    Inflate(Resource.Layout.SpeakerCardView, parent, false);

        SpeakerViewHolder vh = new SpeakerViewHolder(itemView, OnClick);
        return vh;
    }

    private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
}
```

`SpeakerViewHolder.cs` :

```
public class SpeakerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView speakerPhotoImageView { get; private set; }
    public TextView speakerNameTextView { get; private set; }
    public TextView speakerResumeTextView { get; private set; }

    // Get references to the views defined in the CardView layout.
    public SpeakerViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener)
        : base(itemView)
    {
        // Locate and cache view references:
        speakerPhotoImageView = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.speakerPhotoImageView);
        speakerNameTextView = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.speakerNameTextView);

        // Detect user clicks on the item view and report which item
        // was clicked (by layout position) to the listener:
        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);
    }
}
```

`textView_selected.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#6495ED" />
    <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#DCDCDC" />
</shape>
```

`textView_unselected.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#DCDCDC" />
</shape>
```

I've put `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);` in the `GetAllSpeakers` method in `SpeakersActivity` in order to imitate the delay when I get the records from a real database. Tell me if I am missing some file.